# Angular material mat-form-field valid color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to change outline color to green when value entered is valid in a mat-form-field.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
     <input matInput formControlName="maxDaysSupply" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
</mat-form-field>
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide different colors based on the form validation .

mat-form-field has an Input property color .

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [color]="form.valid?'primary':'warn">
```

Get more info on how to setup themes from their website: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: I'm trying to edit outline, which came by default from angular-material, this can apply only on input, as far as I tested.

Comment: Isn't this also only fired if the form is valid but the requested behavior is that the color changes once the form field is valid?